# Save as prompt preference issue while using chrome webdriver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

The problem is that I cannot disable the `Save as prompt` preference on the Chrome web driver in incognito mode. It doesn't work:

```
​​options.AddUserProfilePreference(
     ​​​           "download.default_directory",
                Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Downloads"));
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", true);
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.block_third_party_cookies", false);
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.cookie_controls_mode", 0);
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("--disk-cache-size", 0);
            options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
            options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);

            options.AddArgument("--incognito");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-web-security");
            options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-default-apps");
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            options.AddArgument("--enable-clipboard");
```

I found a temporary solution to turn off it through the `Registry Editor`.